# Python increasing memory usage with exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, memory-leaks, exec

I had some problem with Python 3.7 running a single script in .py format. To Solve this i divided the program in some .py files, even so have memory leak.

> I have a web scraping program that runs some script at intervals so it has to run 24h / 7, but with 16mb / hour memory increase it gets hard.

```
while True:
    with open('scrapy.py') as op:
        exec(op.read())
    time.sleep(5)
```

> Scrapy.py have some requests, pandas etc
>
> I think this code close 'scrapy.py' every time the loop ends, but it seems not since this program eat memory.

Comment: I will have to test this on my laptop, but is this all the code? It seems as if it will launch `scrapy.py` every 5 seconds so if it is still running you are spawning more processes? What OS are you running? Did you check process list ?

Comment: I use Linux from VM.
The mechanism of program is: -> exec(scrappy.py) (wait for time to scrap) -> exec(x.py), exec(y.py) when all that's end(in 5 sec approximately) its back to time.sleep(5) then execute the same process again. 
When I run others scripts with memory leak in while True with no time wait i have no memory lose. This is strange, since in this case the memory is clean